# .net - Encrypt in server decrypt in client

Tags: c#, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I am using a Token based authentication. My web server would generate and encrypt the token. I want the client to decrypt the token to read certain payload information.

What algorithm I should use to achieve this?

In my understanding if I use RSA, I can decrypt in c# using private key whereas the encryption has to happen from other hand so this doesn't fit-in my scenario. Is there any other asymmetric algorithm or ways to achieve this?

- Server encrypt - private key.
- Client decrypt - public key.

Comment: You've got it backwards, the client should present an encrypted token to the server for authorization.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the encryption has to happen from other hand'?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other asymmetric algorithm or ways to achieve this please suggest.

I want to correct your understanding of asymmetric encryption. Asymmetric encryption allows anyone with the public key to send a secret message to anyone with the private key. Since the public key is public, asymmetric encryption allows many possible senders to send private messages to a few special recipients.

> My web server would generate and encrypt the token. I want the client to decrypt the token to read certain payload information.

In that case, with the server sending a secret message to the client, if you are using asymmetric encryption, then the server will encrypt with the public key, and the client will decrypt with the private key.

> Server encrypt - private key. Client decrypt - public key.

That is not correct. In asymmetric cryptography, the public key does the encryption and the private key does the decryption.

What you might be thinking about is a digitally signed message. In that case, the sender signs the message with the private key and the receiver verifies the signature with the public key. Digitally signed messages are not secret, though, whereas encrypted messages are secret.

> Is there any other asymmetric algorithm or ways to achieve this please suggest.

Since your use case is not entirely clear, I will stop the answer there, and leave it at correcting your understanding of asymmetric encryption. It might be that you need symmetric encryption or a digital signature. I encourage you to ask another, separate StackOverflow question as a follow up to this one.

---

As a final note, I'll refer you to the [Internet Security Glossary](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4949). In particular, the section named "$ asymmetric cryptography" has a precise and brief description about how "Asymmetric cryptography can be used to create algorithms for encryption, digital signature, and key agreement."

---

From your other (unfortunately on hold) question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610839/protecting-jwt-signing-and-encryption-c-sharp-solution, it sounds like you require the following:

1. Send a payload from the server to the client.
2. Only the client can read the payload, because it is encrypted.
3. The client can verify who sent the payload, because it is signed.

The recommended approach is to [sign-and-then-encrypt](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-11.2). If you are wanting to use asymmetric encryption for both:

1. use a private to key to sign the payload,
2. then use a public key to encrypt the signed payload.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I've rephrased the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610839/protecting-jwt-signing-and-encryption-c-sharp-solution.

Comment: @Rakesh I've updated the answer based on your other question.